/etc/cups/cupsd.conf - on a share across 2 servers
I have two servers which has to see all the same network printers.
Please advise if I can change the location of the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file to something like /etc instead?
My /etc/cups is the same share(nfs) which is mounted on two diff servers (I need to keep the printers in-sync)
But I assume the "ServerName" line in the cupsd.conf file needs to display the actual hostname of that server where cups starts up on.
So do I need to remove the cupsd.conf file from the /etc/cups/ shared(nfs) folder?
and place it in /etc/ maybe?
Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Why not just create a CUPS server with all of the printers and have the two servers connect to it?
